# Regular expression in javascript to remove anything that is not: a-z 0-9 and hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

Thanks in advance.

I would like a regular expression that removes anything that is NOT alpha numeric and a hyphen. So allowed are A-Z 0-9 and -.

Also, how could I apply that to a string in Javascript?

Thanks again.

Comment: Show us what were your tries. We will do our best to help you fix them.

Comment: replace [^A-Z0-9\-\.]+ with nothing

Comment: Thanks guys. This is the end result. 
String.replace(/[^A-Z0-9\-]/ig,'');

Comment: @Sparkyfied: You don’t need to escape the hyphen in that context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var str = 'a23a-asd!@#$';
str.replace(/[^-a-z0-9]/ig,'');
```

Comment: 'a23a-asd'.replace(/[^-a-z \d]/ig,''); (forgot the \d) :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str = str.replace(/[a-zA-Z\d-]/g, "");
```

Comment: No, `\w` includes underscores which the OP didn't ask for.

Comment: @Andrew Hare: But you first had `[\w\d-]`.

Comment: [\w] ([A-Za-z0-9_]) encompasses all of [\d] ([0-9]), [^\w\d] is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/g, "");
```

Comment: you need the **g**lobal flag on that otherwise it just replaces the first match.

Answer (score 0):

*string*.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g, "");

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#Box, #Window').keyup(function(){
            var $th = $(this);
            $th.val($th.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, function(str){return '';}));
        });

    });
```

This can be used to validate Alphanumeric values.