# How to accept all punctuation from form input

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a language quiz where users can write down their answers, like a translation for example. But I've noticed, when the answer requires punctuation, like a quotation mark, that some devices use a different style of punctuation and that will result in a wrong answer, because the punctuation used in the correct answer is just a bit different.

Here's the javascript I'm using to check answers:

```
<script>
var answers = {
  q1: ["Auto's"]
};

function markAnswers(id) {
  $(`#q${id}`).each(function () {
    if ($.inArray(this.value, answers[this.id]) === -1) {
      $(this).parent().append(`<br><span class='incorrect'>✗ Correct answer = ${answers[this.id]}</span>`);
    } else {
      $(this).parent().append("<br><span class='correct'>✓ Correct!</span>");
    }
  });
}

$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const id = e.target.id.replace("formId", "");
  markAnswers(id);

  $(`#submitId${id}`).each(function () {
    this.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    this.value = "Check answer";
  });
});
</script>
```

As you can see, here I have an answer that requires a single quote ('), but apparently not all single quotes are equal.

I did find some code to replace specific punctuation and it's this: `[^\w\s\']|_`
But I'm not sure how to implement it and I would rather just *accept* the different punctuation. My only concerns are quotation marks and whitespace (as autofill on phones and tablets can create space).

Any suggestion on how to implement this is much appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:**
Based on @Don't Panic's earlier versions of his code below (without .clean and .display) I want to make a few tweaks to it, but before I can, the code below always shows **✗ Correct answer =**  no matter if the answer is typed correctly or not. What could be wrong?

And about the tweaks. I've come to understand that Apple uses Smart Punctuation and this is a feature you can turn off. So I will ask my students to do that. Because I've tested it and without this feature toggled on, it will display a more straight/normal apostrophe and the answer will be accepted as correct. But since apostrophes and perhaps some other punctuation like a comma will be important, I want to add those to the existing line of code `^a-zA-Z\d`. And I was thinking to at least ignore periods and extra spaces.

Thank you for all the help!

```
// Write out your answers without punctuation
var answers = {
  q1: ["Autos"]
};

function markAnswers(id) {
  $(`#q${id}`).each(function () {

    // First, strip out any punctuation the user has entered
    let userAnswer = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/g,'');

    // Now check if that "cleaned" value matches your answer
    if ($.inArray(userAnswer, answers[this.id]) === -1) {
      $(this).parent().append(`<br><span class='incorrect'>✗ Correct answer = ${answers[this.id]}</span>`);
    } else {
      $(this).parent().append("<br><span class='correct'>✓ Correct!</span>");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: How about just removing everything non-alphanumeric? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487422/regular-expression-in-javascript-to-remove-anything-that-is-not-a-z-0-9-and-hyp

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks for answering. I checked it. But it says "So allowed are A-Z 0-9 and -", which means quotation marks aren't accepted? But they are important in some of my answers.

Comment: The only time I see `.replace()` is when the literal "formId" is removed. Where is this replace that uses `[^\w\s']|_`? BTW, if you really want to accept everything but an underscore then it should just be `_`.

Comment: @zer00ne I haven't implemented it. I just found this line of code for this type of problem-solving. And validating underscores aren't necessary, as they will not be part of answers anyway. This line of code is just an example. I'm definitely not an expert.

Answer (score 2):

Take the user's input, strip out all punctuation, do the same to your answer, and compare the two. This way a user can use any punctuation they like, but it will just be stripped out and not part of the comparison.

This won't work if your questions are eg related to grammar, eg if you are testing when and where an apostrophe is correct, of course - in those cases the apostrophe *is* the answer!

The exact regular expression will depend on what has to be in your questions.  Let's say you need all uppper- and lower-case letters and numbers:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    markAnswers(1)
});

// Correct answers
var answers = {
    "q1": "Auto's"
};

function markAnswers(id) {

  $(`#q${id}`).each(function () {

    // First, strip out any punctuation the user has entered
    let userAnswer = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/g,'');
    
    // Strip any punctuation from the right answer
    let correct = answers[this.id].replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/g,'');

    // Now check if they match
    if (userAnswer !== correct) {
      $(this).parent().append(`<br><span class='incorrect'>✗ Correct answer = ${answers[this.id]}</span>`);
    } else {
      $(this).parent().append("<br><span class='correct'>✓ Correct!</span>");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    What is the plural of <b>Auto</b>?
    <input id='q1' type='text'>
    <button>Check!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. You're right, I meant apostrophe instead of a single quote. Anyway, this is definitely a solution. However, it indeed doesn't work if, as you said already, the apostrophe is part of the correct answer. For example, if they write something incorrect, the correct answer will be displayed, but in this case without an apostrophe. Then I'm showing them a misspelled answer.

Comment: I see, I didn't notice you display the correct answer.  I've updated my answer to handle that.

Comment: I used to develop short quizzes and that's the best way to deal with one off punctuation from users.

Comment: I added a working snippet to demonstate it better.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thanks! Your snippet works flawlessly and it looks good. Unfortunately on my side it always gives me **✗ Correct answer = Auto's** no matter if I enter it correctly or not. I did change `$('button')` to `$('submit')` as I'm using a submit input button, but it's not making any difference. Otherwise I cannot see what else is different. Even so, since the apostrophe is part of having a correct answer, this is unfortunately not THE solution. Nevertheless, it's definitely a step in the right direction! Thanks!

Comment: @Don'tPanic I've edited my question. Could you take a look? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your new question - your code works fine for me.

I've added a button handler to actually run the check, but otherwise this is a copy-paste of your code.

- If I type *asdf*, I get "*✗ Correct answer = Autos*", which is correct;
- If I type *autos*, I get "*✗ Correct answer = Autos*", which is correct (lower case "a" instead of "A");
- If I type *Autos*, I get "*✓ Correct!*", which is correct;
- If I type *"Auto's"* (including those quotes), I get "*✓ Correct!*", which is correct;

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    markAnswers(1)
});

// Write out your answers without punctuation
var answers = {
  q1: ["Autos"]
};

function markAnswers(id) {
  $(`#q${id}`).each(function () {

    // First, strip out any punctuation the user has entered
    let userAnswer = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/g,'');

    // Now check if that "cleaned" value matches your answer
    if ($.inArray(userAnswer, answers[this.id]) === -1) {
      $(this).parent().append(`<br><span class='incorrect'>✗ Correct answer = ${answers[this.id]}</span>`);
    } else {
      $(this).parent().append("<br><span class='correct'>✓ Correct!</span>");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    What is the plural of <b>Auto</b>?
    <input id='q1' type='text'>
    <button>Check!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you once again! I guess I had to add `$('button').on('click', function() markAnswers(1) });` at the start of the script and then it worked. I have now tweaked the RegExp to `[^\w\'\,\-\?\!\"\:\—]`. And everything seems to be working correctly. I've added the ones that could be part of the correct answer in the future. Thank you again. I really appreciate it (Y)